# Tokenize Strings using Pointers in ANSI C

Tags: c, string, tokenize, ansi-c

This is in Ansi C. I am given a string. I am supposed to create a method that returns an array of character pointers that point to the beginning of each word of said string. I am not allowed to use Malloc, but instead told that the maximum length of input will be 80.

Also, before anyone flames me for not searching the forum, I can't use strtok :(

```
char input[80] = "hello world, please tokenize this string"
```

and the output of the method should have 6 elements;

```
output[0] points to the "h",
output[1] points to the "w",
```

and so on.

How should I write the method?

Also, I need a similar method to handle input from a file with maximum of 110 lines.

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Yes, it is homework, but due date has already passed. Just asking out of curiosity now.

Comment: Ok, consider stepping through the input string using a pointer, stopping when the value pointed to equals a space character and there you have a word.  Continue doing this until end of string '\0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
boolean isInWord = false
while (*ptr != NUL character) {
   if (!isInWord and isWordCharacter(*ptr)) {
       isInWord = true
       save ptr
   } else if (isInWord and !isWordCharacter(*ptr)) {
       isInWord = false
   }
   increment ptr
}
```

`isWordCharacter` checks whether the character is part of the word or not. Depending on your definition, it can be only alphabet character (recognize `part-time` as 2 words), or it may include `-` (recognize `part-time` as one word).

Answer (score 0):

Because it's homework here's a part of what you might need:

```
char* readPtr = input;
char* wordPtr = input;
int wordCount = 0;
while (*readPtr++ != ' ');
/* Here we have a word from wordPtr to readPtr-1 */
output[wordCount++] = /* something... :)  */
```

You'll need that in a loop, and must consider how to move onto the next word, and check for end of input.

Comment: Checking `!=' '` is not a good idea, since the string can be `"comma , , , , a lot ,"` and you will recognize `,` as a word.

Comment: This is true, instead I'd suggest creating an array of delimiters and checking readPtr against those.  This was just a suggestion of how to get started :)